# JVM flags -XX:+UseDynamicNumberOfGCThreads -XX:+TraceDynamicGCThreads enabled to see no. of GC threads during GC. Please explain the output logs?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jvm-hotspot

We have an application running Wildfly app server in a clustered mode (6 nodes). 
We are seeing sometimes JVM freeze of 16secs when there is a GC triggered. 
The application is time sensitive and other nodes in the cluster thinks that node is dead (in which the JVM pause) if the heartbeat response is not received with in 15secs.
So, The JVM freeze causing application instability. 
To understand what is going on during GC, we enabled hotspot, safepoint logs and see the following traces when there is a GC pause.

Can anybody explain what is meant by the following parameters.

```
1.) active_workers(): 13  
2.) new_acitve_workers: 13  
3.) prev_active_workers: 13
4.) active_workers_by_JT: 3556  
5.) active_workers_by_heap_size: 146
```

**Environment details:**
  Linux 64bit RHEL 7
  OpenJDK 1.8
  Heap size: 12GB (Young:4GB, Tenure:8GB)
  CPU cores: 16
  VMware ESX 5.1

**JVM Arguments:**

```
-XX:ThreadStackSize=512 
-Xmx12288m 
-XX:+UseParallelGC 
-XX:+UseParallelOldGC 
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m 
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-XX:NewSize=4096m 
-XX:MaxNewSize=4096m 
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m 
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseDynamicNumberOfGCThreads
```

Any suggestions in tuning these JVM parameters to reduce the GC pause time?

**GC logs:**

```
GCTaskManager::calc_default_active_workers() : active_workers(): 13  new_acitve_workers: 13  prev_active_workers: 13
 active_workers_by_JT: 3556  active_workers_by_heap_size: 146
GCTaskManager::set_active_gang(): all_workers_active()  1  workers 13  active  13  ParallelGCThreads 13
JT: 1778  workers 13  active  13  idle 0  more 0
2016-10-06T07:38:47.281+0530: 48313.522: [Full GC (Ergonomics) DrainStacksCompactionTask::do_it which = 3 which_stack_index = 3/empty(0) use all workers 1
DrainStacksCompactionTask::do_it which = 7 which_stack_index = 7/empty(0) use all workers 1
DrainStacksCompactionTask::do_it which = 2 which_stack_index = 2/empty(0) use all workers 1
DrainStacksCompactionTask::do_it which = 0 which_stack_index = 0/empty(0) use all workers 1
DrainStacksCompactionTask::do_it which = 11 which_stack_index = 11/empty(0) use all workers 1
DrainStacksCompactionTask::do_it which = 6 which_stack_index = 6/empty(0) use all workers 1
DrainStacksCompactionTask::do_it which = 1 which_stack_index = 1/empty(0) use all workers 1
DrainStacksCompactionTask::do_it which = 12 which_stack_index = 12/empty(0) use all workers 1
DrainStacksCompactionTask::do_it which = 4 which_stack_index = 4/empty(0) use all workers 1
DrainStacksCompactionTask::do_it which = 5 which_stack_index = 5/empty(0) use all workers 1
DrainStacksCompactionTask::do_it which = 9 which_stack_index = 9/empty(0) use all workers 1
DrainStacksCompactionTask::do_it which = 8 which_stack_index = 8/empty(0) use all workers 1
DrainStacksCompactionTask::do_it which = 10 which_stack_index = 10/empty(0) use all workers 1
StealRegionCompactionTask::do_it region_stack_index 3 region_stack = 0x780be610  empty (1) use all workers 1
StealRegionCompactionTask::do_it region_stack_index 5 region_stack = 0x780be730  empty (1) use all workers 1
StealRegionCompactionTask::do_it region_stack_index 7 region_stack = 0x780be850  empty (1) use all workers 1
StealRegionCompactionTask::do_it region_stack_index 11 region_stack = 0x780bea90  empty (1) use all workers 1
StealRegionCompactionTask::do_it region_stack_index 1 region_stack = 0x780be4f0  empty (1) use all workers 1
StealRegionCompactionTask::do_it region_stack_index 10 region_stack = 0x780bea00  empty (1) use all workers 1
StealRegionCompactionTask::do_it region_stack_index 8 region_stack = 0x780be8e0  empty (1) use all workers 1
StealRegionCompactionTask::do_it region_stack_index 4 region_stack = 0x780be6a0  empty (1) use all workers 1
StealRegionCompactionTask::do_it region_stack_index 0 region_stack = 0x780be460  empty (1) use all workers 1
StealRegionCompactionTask::do_it region_stack_index 2 region_stack = 0x780be580  empty (1) use all workers 1
StealRegionCompactionTask::do_it region_stack_index 6 region_stack = 0x780be7c0  empty (1) use all workers 1
StealRegionCompactionTask::do_it region_stack_index 12 region_stack = 0x780beb20  empty (1) use all workers 1
StealRegionCompactionTask::do_it region_stack_index 9 region_stack = 0x780be970  empty (1) use all workers 1
[PSYoungGen: 63998K->0K(4082176K)] [ParOldGen: 8346270K->3657870K(8388608K)] 8410268K->3657870K(12470784K), [Metaspace: 465864K->465775K(1495040K)], 16.0898939 secs] 
[Times: user=180.57 sys=2.46, real=16.09 secs]
2016-10-06T07:39:03.373+0530: 48329.615: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 16.2510644 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0036805 seconds
```

### Safepoint Logs:

```
48313.363: ParallelGCFailedAllocation       [    2384          0              2    ]      [     0     0     3    35 16210    ]  0
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What's the nature of your application? Any huge long-lived objects, on-heap cache etc.? Any huge xml payloads?

Comment: There is a xml processing involved but not so frequent. The xml file size will be around 50KB. the application will fetch the xml files from 60K nodes and processes it for every 15mins.

Comment: Will it be useful to give PalallelGCThread as JVM argument? currently it is calculated (13 GC threads) internally based on the no. of cores (16 cores). Also will there be any improvement if -XX:HeapSizePerThread is tuned?

Comment: Please check my answer, I hope it will give you some ideas

Comment: the GC throughput is much lower than it should be. since things like swap or transparent huge pages would show up as kernel time (which is low)... maybe it's the virtualization?

Comment: @the8472 Is there any JVM flag which allows to print the GC throughput in hotspot logs? And how to troubleshoot such issues?

Comment: @the8472 if it's virtualization it would be noticable during usual load as well, so I think it's a wrong direction. The GC pattern is flawed anyway no matter how fast it's being collected. But let's check anyway.

Comment: Could you please add following metrics at the moment of a Full GC: loadavg, VMWare  Ready%, VMWare Co-stop.

Comment: @bashnesnos a GC cycle is likely to place a far higher load on the memory subsystem of the hypervisor than regular activity because it'll end up a lot of pages at once. so if the system is oversubscribed or has to copy-on-write zero pages or some magic like that it would disproportionally affect GC. but yeah, i'm just speculating

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the `ParallelGCFailedAllocation` and `[PSYoungGen: 63998K->0K(4082176K)] [ParOldGen: 8346270K->3657870K(8388608K)] 8410268K->3657870K(12470784K), [Metaspace: 465864K->465775K(1495040K)], 16.0898939 secs]` we have the following conditions:

1. YoungGen is almost empty (only 63М occupied out of 4G)
2. OldGen is almost full (only 42М left out of 8,3G)
3. JVM tried to move survived objects from YoungGen or failed allocate them in Survivor space and decided to move them to OldGen
4. OldGen had insufficient space as well (only 42M as mentioned) so a FullGC was triggered
5. After a FullGC 5G of OldGen is collected (8346270K->3657870K)

Even 13 GC threads running in parallel are collecting those 5G for 16 seconds. Since you have only 16 cores there not so many room for speed improvement from adding more threads.

The following might be happening here:

- **Your objects live too long for a YounGen**, therefore you would need to switch to CMS/G1 so it will collect OldGen more frequently and it will take less time in total. You would need to tune `InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent` as per your needs. Jugding by current output you should initiate somewhere around 4G. Though it will put in question if you really need those 12G of heap, since it would be a subject to heap fragmentation issues.
- **Your objects are short-lived but too big to be accomodated in Survivor space**, therefore you would need to tune `SurvivorRatio` parameter to make it bigger. Something like SurvivorRatio=4 (it will make it 1G in that case).

So it really depends on your object allocation pattern. The best approach would be to try it somewhere else before applying it in production.

[JVM GC parameters could be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html)

Comment: There will be around 1K minor GCs and 5-8 Full GCs will be happening in an hour. So, will it be good idea to remove the 'NewSize' and 'MaxNewSize' parameters and allow the JVM to allocate based on the need. Will it give any improvement? Also increasing the parallel GC threads will it help??

Comment: @PurushothamYanamala Removing NewSize/MaxNewSize would more likely add more space for OldGen therefore Full GCs count might drop a bit, but the Full GC pause time will increase as well - so it won't add any benefits. Increasing parralell GC threads won't help any more, since you can't add more than 3 - refer to Amdal's law.

Comment: Something is fishy. 180 seconds worth of CPU cycles and a live data set of 3.6GB means the GC throughput is only 20MB per core-second.

Comment: @the8472 indeed, either it could be enourmous GC roots or poor-written custom `finalize()`. Thanks for a good catch, we could ask if any custom finalizers present.

Comment: @PurushothamYanamala does your/any 3rd party code have any custom finalizers (i.e. any classes that override the `finalize()` method)?

Comment: it's a huge codebase and I can't really tell if there are any custom finalize() methods. Also the application uses lot of 3rd party libraries. @the8472 what could possibly cause the GC throughput? does it anything to do with filesystem? We are using tmpfs to write GC and safepoint logs which will have high IO read/write rate as it uses virtual memory. What are the ways to increase GC throughput??

Comment: @PurushothamYanamala you can check if IO causing any troubles by analysing TOP during GC (or any monitoring which records %user, %sys and %iowait). If %iowait is significant compared to %user you than IO is causing troubles.

Comment: @bashnesnos Let me check the iostats during Full GC time and will comeback with the data. Need another clarification here, does JVM uses Disk IO during GC or it uses virtual memory?

Comment: @PurushothamYanamala it uses IO (depending on type of filesystem) for writing logs, since you have `PrintGCTaskTimeStamps` option enabled it could cause some excsessive logging and concurrency amongst those 13 threads, and it could cause delays potentially.

Comment: @bashnesnos I have created a separate drive in tmpfs file system to write the hotspot and safepoint logs. The advantage of tmpfs file system over disk is that it uses the virtual memory to store the logs. The IO performance is too good in tmpfs. the /etc/fstab entry is -> tmpfs                   /hotspot_tmp            tmpfs   size=3g         0 0

Comment: @PurushothamYanamala unless there is memory shortage/ballooning in your VM, yes there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125191/discussion-between-bashnesnos-and-purushotham-yanamala).