# JVM Minor GC is taking more time

Tags: java, performance, jvm, wildfly

We have an application running Wildfly app server in a clustered mode (6 nodes). We are seeing sometimes JVM freeze of 15secs when there is a minor GC triggered. The JVM freeze causing application instability. 
We enabled the PrintTenuringDistribution and the following traces are observed.

```
2016-10-13T13:49:05.000+0530: 83.471: [GC (Allocation Failure) GCTaskManager::calc_default_active_workers() : active_workers(): 13  new_acitve_workers: 13  prev_active_workers: 13
```

active_workers_by_JT: 1110  active_workers_by_heap_size: 46
GCTaskManager::set_active_gang(): all_workers_active()  1  workers 13  active  13  ParallelGCThreads 13
JT: 555  workers 13  active  13  idle 0  more 0

Desired survivor size 733478912 bytes, new threshold 11 (max 15)

**JVM Arguments**

```
-XX:ThreadStackSize=512 
-Xmx12288m 
-XX:+UseParallelGC 
-XX:+UseParallelOldGC 
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m 
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-XX:NewSize=4096m 
-XX:MaxNewSize=4096m 
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m 
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseDynamicNumberOfGCThreads
```

**Environment details:** Linux 64bit RHEL 7 OpenJDK 1.8 Heap size: 12GB (Young:4GB, Tenure:8GB) CPU cores: 16 VMware ESX 5.1

Any suggestion on improving the Young GC time?

Comment: log with `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` and post a longer excerpt of the log. And please format it properly when editing your question.

Comment: Is it a different app from the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891275/jvm-flags-xxusedynamicnumberofgcthreads-xxtracedynamicgcthreads-enabled-to ?

Comment: @bashnesnos it is the same app but different issue.